# Is it possible to use tableView.moveRow for a table with a dynamic number of sections?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create a table with a dynamic number of sections. This is causing tableView.moveRow to crash with even though I've updated data source prior to calling it.

E.g.)

> A B | --- A and B in a list. Number of sections = 1, rows in section = 2
>
> A | B --- A in section 0 and B in section 1. Number of sections = 2, rows in each section = 1

I keep getting Assertion failure in `-[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:]` and I'm wondering if this is something outside the reach of UITableView or if I just have a bug in my code?

My code is

```
let (fromPath, toPath) = viewModel.moveItem(A) // Creates new section and moves A to the new section below
dprint("Move \(A.name) from \(fromPath) to \(toPath)")
tableView.moveRow(at: fromPath, to: toPath)
```

Output is

> Move A from [0, 0] to [1, 0]
>
> 2018-01-23 13:59:45.705931+0100 MyApp[44553:638288] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3698.33.6/UITableView.m:1826

Comment: any luck solving it with my answer?

Comment: Not yet, but I now know that I have bug in my code. Thank you. @MilanNosáľ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose changes to the `tableView` using `tableView.beginUpdates()` and `tableView.endUpdates()`.

Moreover, you have to take care of creating new sections too, while changing the data model will create a new section in data, you will have to tell the `tableView` to insert a new one before moving the row:

```
let (fromPath, toPath) = viewModel.moveItem(A) // Creates new section and moves A to the new section below
dprint("Move \(A.name) from \(fromPath) to \(toPath)")
tableView.beginUpdates()
if newSectionWasCreated {
    tableView.insertSections([toPath.section], with: .automatic)
}
tableView.moveRow(at: fromPath, to: toPath)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

You'll have to figure out how to determine `newSectionWasCreated` yourself based on the model.

Comment: ***Always** enclose ... beginUpdates() ... endUpdates()* is wrong. It is only required for 2 or more consecutive ***simultaneous*** `insert/delete/move` operations like in your example. But it is **not** required generally.